# Is there a way for postman to read the response data from a GET request and then use an IF THEN statement to run a POST request?

Tags: api, server, postman

At the time of writing this question, I was attempting to get Postman to send a GET request, Read the response, and use that response to send a POST Request.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I am not sure where the data of the GET request is stored, and I do not know how to access it.

Where is this data stored, if anywhere, and how can I use it?

Comment: please add more details like an example to help people know what exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pre-requisite add:

```
// set initial value
const method = pm.variables.get("method")
// set initial value as GET if method is undefined
method ? null : pm.variables.set("method", "GET")

// Set this as method
pm.request.method =method
```

in test script add :

```
// the condition check
if (pm.response.json().somevalue === "somevalue") {
    
    //then change the method
    pm.variables.set("method", "POST")

    //call the same request again using setNExtRequest
    // pm.info.reqeustName gives current request's name
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}
```

Comment: Hi, "then change the method" reported an error, is this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: @KniteRite yes  updated it sorry

Comment: is there also supposed to be a space in pm.request.method =method ??

Comment: it doesn't matter in javascript ,